# How to configure fstab to mount a remote directory without including its subdirectories?

Tags: fstab

How should I configure fstab to mount a remote directory but without including its subdirectories but only the directly (1th level) contained files?

Answer (score 0):

Not at all. I'm not aware of any file system that supports that.

Remark: Sounds like you're solving a "strange" problem. Maybe ask a new question about what you're trying to solve rather than what you think you need to mount to solve it!

Comment: it's only one directory I need (contains some configuration) while the other are kind of temporary specific to the local system directories

Comment: so, ignore them.

Comment: I can't. The mount-to system is identical to mount-from one and it'll create same temporarily files which might overlap with the mount-from ones.

Comment: Ah! Sure you don't want to use symlinks then?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, what do you mean by that?

Comment: use a symbolic link to "represent" the original files in a different place (or different name); `ln -s` (see `man ls`, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link#POSIX_and_Unix-like_operating_systems))

Answer (score 0):

Depending on Your computing system and file system You could set directory privileges to a value that does not allow access to subdirectories for non-privileged users (e.g. `chmod -R 000 /mounted/subdirectories/`).
This would be a workaround for mounting only a 1st level directory on a remote unix server file system, like for ext types.

Comment: it's not an option for me; the mount-to system is identical to mount-from one and that's why I need to mount: to have some configuration files from the "mount-from" system